# Magento Community Edition Patches / Notifications backend

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Maybe I've got a stupid question, but I'm not sure about it, hope this is the right place for this question.

Since 11 december there's a new security patch (PATCH_SUPEE-2518_CE_1.5.1.0-1.7.0.2_v1.sh), which I've installed through SSH. That went all ok, no errors. The script said: 
Patch was applied / reverted succesfully.

After doing this i logged in the backend en cleared all the caches, but the notification for the patch is still visible in the backend. Is that normal for Magento, doesn't it see that the patch is installed? Can I discard the message so my customer doesn't see it? And how can I check if the patch is working correct.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's just a standard magento backend notification, you can delete it or mark it as read. Until you do so; the notification will continue to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications have little to do with core code, they're just an RSS feed from Magento HQ (and any extension vendors). If you've applied the patch and your store is running correctly then you should be fine.

In the admin panel, just go to System > Notifications and set them all to "read". You should no longer be bugged by the popups.